# VS2017 delete NuGet files in post build event

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

What is the order of execution of project post build events related to a NuGet package copying its files? I have a NuGet package that copies unnecessary files to my output directory (there are both DLLs and EXEs, in my case I don't need the latter). The usual idea of

```
del /f /q "$(TargetDir)directory\*.exe"
```

doesn't work, very probably it's called before VS (MSBuild) actually copies those files.

Comment: It will not be NuGet copying files to the output directory it will be MSBuild. What exactly does your NuGet package look like? I am assuming it has all these files in a lib directory so NuGet will add references to these in the project file. If you want to avoid that I would look at using a custom MSBuild targets file in the NuGet package so you can customize the build or maybe just add any .exe files to a tools folder in the NuGet package. However I am not sure exactly what you want the NuGet package to do.

Comment: Also: `packages.config` based project or using the new `ProjectReference` system? (latter one is able to excluded assets (compile/contentFIles/...) from packages)

Comment: The new one. With the earlier (package folder), yes, I could simply modify the local copy of the package and remove the unnecessary files. But it's not that simple with the newer caching mechanism. I don't really want to change the NuGet if I can avoid it. I simply want to delete a few unnecessary files from my output after everything has been done. I'll check out that exclusion.

Comment: After changing the MSBuild log to detail(Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run), you will find that the actually copies operation was completed before the post-build event executed. You can use use `echo <Message..>` to explicitly log that a target was executed. So you should double check why the delete command line not delete the .exe file. BTW, is that package custom? If not, you can share the package ID to me and which file you don not want to copy, I will test it.

Comment: iMobileDevice-net, there will be two win7-xxx folders with both DLLs and EXEs, the second are unnecessary for the programs to run. I don't know why they're there in the first place, I'll contact the developer about it but I thought it would be easy to delete them no matter what. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you log idea was rather good, I checked out and, at least for me, it's as I suspected. I replaced the delete with a simple echo and the package `CopyNativeBinaries` target comes four steps *after* `PostBuildEvent`.

Comment: `<Target Name="CopyNativeBinaries" AfterTargets="Build">`, this is from the package targets file. I've never built such packages myself so I can't really judge whether this is usual of something I have to complain about. :-)

Comment: @Gábor, yes, the `<Target Name="CopyNativeBinaries" AfterTargets="Build">` is the culprit of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> very probably it's called before VS (MSBuild) actually copies those files.

According to the info in the comment:

> the `<Target Name="CopyNativeBinaries" AfterTargets="Build">`, this is
>   from the package targets file.

This import MSBuild target would executed copy task after build completed, which cause delete command line in the post-build to fail. That is the reason why `CopyNativeBinaries` target comes four steps after `PostBuildEvent`.

To resolve this issue, we could convert the post-build event command line to the target with the order after target `CopyNativeBinaries`:

Detail Steps:

1. Remove the post-build event.
2. Unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag, place below scripts:

   ```
   <Target Name="DeleteFile" AfterTargets="CopyNativeBinaries">
     <ItemGroup>
       <FileToDelete Include="$(TargetDir)directory\*.exe"/>
     </ItemGroup>
     <Exec Command="del /F /Q &quot;@(FileToDelete)&quot;"/>
   </Target>
   ```

After this setting, the `DeleteFile` will executed after the target `CopyNativeBinaries`.

Comment: Thanks, almost. Del didn't really like the list of files provided, so a more straightforward solution of giving it the wildcard directly solved it. Very nice idea and very logical in hindsight. :-) `<Exec Command="del /F /Q &quot;$(TargetDir)directory\*.exe&quot;"/>`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (MSBUILD v15)

```
<Target Name="BeforeClean">
  <Exec Command="del /F /Q $(TargetDir)*.exe"/>
  <Exec Command="del /F /Q $(TargetDir)*.example"/>
</Target>
```